# Alternative to Photoshop's Stamp filter in GIMP

Tags: gimp, image-editing, filter

In Photoshop using *Filter > Sketch > Stamp* you can create an effect similar to the image below:

[image]

Is there any plugin or any way to do this in GIMP?

P.S: in GIMP *Color > Desaturate* is not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I could get using GIMP (without any plugin):

[image]

First I applied Filter > Artistic > Photocopy, then applied contrast-brightness two times...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Filters > Edge-detect > Difference of Gaussians... could give a similar effect. Maybe with some added Filters > Noise. There are probably better ways to do this. Didn't have time to investigate further though. G'Mic filter addon surely has something for this too.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [G'MIC plugin](http://gmic.eu/) for GIMP - it has a Stamp filter.  Once you've installed G'MIC and restarted GIMP, find it at Filters > G'MIC > expand the Black and White filters, the Stamp filter is in the list.

It's not exactly the same, but quite close.  I suppose you could add another filter first to get a bit more edge defintion before applying the Stamp filter. Anyway, this example is just the plain ordinary Stamp filter from G'MIC.

[image]

Here's another attempt where I ran the regular GIMP Cartoon filter a couple of times before applying the G'MIC Stamp filter.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

From the experience I've had with GIMP, you can't achieve the same look... However I would suggest that you play around with the contrast. I would also suggest de-saturizing the image first, and then play around with the contrast to see how much or how little you want. You can find it under Colours > Brightness-Contrast.
If you put the contrast way up, there's only a small amount of colour which shines through - that's why you should de-saturate first, as well. It'll give you only the shades (graytones), or will turn completely white and black in the end...
Hope that helped!

Answer (score -1):

Use Gimp's "photocopy" filter, and move all the sliders completely to the right.  That is as close as you are going to get to the Photoshop "stamp" filter.

Mark

Comment: How exactly does this add anything to the accepted answer?

Comment: @joojaa: It tells you what to do with the sliders. That’s not much, I admit, but it’s not a duplicate answer. Still, more details would be good.